# ¿Cómo puedo actualizar una variable y pasarle el valor de un JSON en android studio?

Tags: android, json, volley

introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: como pueden ver estoy usando android studiio y la libreria volley para traer datos JSON]imgur.com/GImkY.png

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Aparte de lo que se te ha sugerido en el comentario anterior, considera también poner el texto como código y no como imagen. Pulsa en [edit] para mejorar tu pregunta.

Comment: Agrega el código como texto no como imagen por favor.